# Sources that clothes should be treated respectfully

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, clothing

I have developed a sensitivity towards treating clothes respectfully. An example is I try not to throw clothing all over the floor (cleanliness aside). I was wondering if there are any sources which discuss the idea of treating clothes respectfully, as either a matter of *halacha* or *derech eretz*.

I am coming from various sources that I have seen which seem to indicate that clothing is something to treat properly. For example:

1. Dovid HaMelech was [punished](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Kings.1.1) (see Rashi [*ad. loc*](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_I_Kings.1.1.1)) for [cutting](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.24.5) King Shaul's clothing. Despite the fact that [one](https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_I_Samuel.24.6.1) could argue this was because the clothes belonged to the King, Chazal seem to [speak](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.62b.10) in broad terms.
2. There seems to be great value given to clothing the naked. Hashem is [praised](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.14a.6) for clothing the naked, a *bracha* was [instituted](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.60b.5) regarding it, it's considered a [mitzvah](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.14a.4). I would think that this would attach some importance to the clothes themselves, as they're a tool to help others.
3. Rabbi Yochanan would [refer](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.113a.14) to his clothing as that which honors him. I would imagine it's [appropriate](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.2.30) to honor that which honors you.

I found [this](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/90172) *teshuvah* online, which says that a person shouldn't throw their clothes on the floor disrespectfully, but no source was given.

(To clarify, I'm not looking for sources specifically about clothes on the floor. That's just an example.)

Comment: Fwiw, my father is very mapkid on keeping clothes, even dirty clothes, off of the floor.

Comment: I'm surmising that the importance of clothes emanates from how G-d clothed Adam & Chava because they were embarrassed being naked. Perhaps, in a sense, treating clothes respectfully is our way of constantly recognizing G-d's gift.

Comment: This a model question! You clearly states what you are looking for, it shows lots of previous research, and is well written. Kudos to you, I wish I could upvote twice. (Btw, this is not to say that there aren't many other great questions, but with a lot of weak questions lately (myself included) it seems worth highlighting.)

Comment: I wonder if keeping clothes nice is related to *tzni'ut*. There are numerous sources for that. Maybe wearing wrinkled, messy, dirty clothes (throwing clothes on the ground, etc. will do this) is related to not being bitzni'ut.

Comment: @DanF the nafka mina being dirty clothes before they go in the wash. If we translate not tsnenuah as undignified maybe I can hear what you're saying...

Comment: @robev  I think part of *tzni'ut* may extend to the notion that a person should be careful not to soil his clothes in the first place. Clothes will get "dirty" regardless, so this would mean, also, not to wear dirty laundry as well. IIRC, theer's a strict rule that a *Talmid Chcham* gets a severe penalty if he dresses in dirty wrinkled clothes.

Comment: The Gemara says a Talmid Chakham shouldn't go out with a stain on his clothes. Fwiw.

Comment: @robev Well, there is a practice of deliberately throwing clean clothes on the floor to make them dirty enough to wear during the Nine Days

Comment: @DoubleAA I alluded to that in my comment. Where in Gemarah does it mention this about a Talmid Chacham?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the prohibition of baal tashschit (not destroying/treating objects respectfully) does apply to clothing as well.

The gemara in [Shabbat 105b](https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.105b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) cites a baraita

> **One who rends his garments in his anger**, or who breaks his vessels in
>   his anger, or who scatters his money in his anger, **should be like an
>   idol worshipper in your eyes**, as that is the craft of the evil
>   inclination.

The Rambam in [Hilchot Melachim 6:10](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188350/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-6.htm) writes

> This prohibition does not apply to trees alone. Rather, **anyone who**
>   breaks utensils, **tears garments**, destroys buildings, stops up a
>   spring, or ruins food with a destructive intent **transgresses the
>   command 'Do not destroy.'** However, he is not lashed. Instead, he
>   receives stripes for rebellious conducts instituted by the Sages.

Regarding tearing kria (tearing a vestment in mourning), [chabad.org notes](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1892179/jewish/Judaism-and-Environmentalism-Bal-Tashchit.htm)

> There are limitations to what is considered “needless” destruction.
>   Observance of a mitzvah, like tearing clothes in mourning, or
>   preservation of human life or health, overrules bal tashchit when the
>   two come into conflict.

Comment: I think there also may be something similar to your 1st citation mentioned in Avot DeRav Natan. I'll see if I can locate it.

Comment: What about non destructive but non respectful usage? I understand Dovid tore the shirt but I'm still wondering about other cases as well

Comment: @robev I asked a shailo about tearing kriyah for a non-Jew and it was explained to me (although quickly) that baal taschit was the main, if not only, potential reason not to. I think all the other answers here are in concurrence that disrespecting clothing is not a problem of its own (although I have heard the thing DoubleAA brought about not going out with a stain).

Answer (score 2):

The rabbis of [din.org.il](http://din.org.il/2012/02/29/%D7%91%D7%99%D7%96%D7%95%D7%99-%D7%91%D7%92%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D/) were asked where one can find the halachic source prohibiting treating clothes disrespectfully.

They answered:

> לא מצאנו בהלכה דין זל "ביזוי" במה שמתבטא בשימוש לא יפה וכד’, אלא רק שאין לזרוק לאשפה דבר שאפשר להשתמש בו, וכן לא לשבור דבר שראוי לשימוש, והוא גם בכלל איסור בל תשחית
>
> אבל מותר להשתמש בבגדים בתשמישים מגונים, כגון לשטוף בהם רצפה וכיוצא בזה
>
> We have not found in halacha a law regarding "disrespect" [of clothing] in terms of usage in a not nice manner etc. Rather, only that one may not throw in the trash something which can still be used, and also not to destroy something usable, which also falls under the prohibition of *bal taschchit*.
>
> But it is permited to use clothing for degrading purposes, for example to clean the floor with them, and other similar uses.
>
> *(my translation)*